# Check if array contains specific string in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to store urls from universities in an array, check if elements contain ".ec" in the end. If they do, then strip the "www." and the ".edu"

So far this is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np


def localuniversities():
    sites = input("Enter sites separated by a comma and space: ").lower().split(", ")
    arraysites = np.asarray(sites)
    print(arraysites)
    matching = [s for s in arraysites if ".ec" in s]
    arraysites1 = [url.rstrip(".edu.ec") for url in matching]
    arraysites2 = [url.strip("www.").upper() for url in arraysites1]
    unique = np.unique(arraysites2, axis=0)
    print(unique)


print(localuniversities())
```

EDIT: Managed to fix the verification.

I still have the problem that if I enter a site and the word ends with a "d", such as "www.harvard.edu", it will strip the "d" aswell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ooooh.  Lots to discuss.  First, why are you using `numpy` for string data?  Just use Python's lists etc.  Second, you want to create a function to do your checking.  Right now, check is a one-time-evaluated variable.  You want to check each item in array sites independently.  And what is the `str` input of your overall function?

Comment: Strings in an array are limited to the dtype length, determined when array was created.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I redid my verification variable and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First one is that if I enter a site, say "www.harvard.edu", it will strip the D off it so it comes out as "HARVAR".

this is happening because the `rstrip` function get a collection of characters to strip from the end of the string, not a whole word to strip if it exists. (a string is a collection of characters). this is also true for the `strip` function. that is why the `D` was removed.

> Second is that its not verifying as far as I can tell.

as @Jeff_h said, this is because you define the `check` variable only once, which will cause the for loop to either `strip` and `rstrip` all sites, or not.

after fixing all the problems, here is what I got

```
def localuniversities():
    sites = input("Enter sites separated by a comma and space: ").lower().split(", ")
    temp = []
    for site in sites:
        if site.endswith(".ec"):
            temp.append(site[site.find("www") + len("www") + 1:site.rfind(".edu.ec")])
    return temp


print(localuniversities())
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you! It really helped. The way you made the code so simple is neat as hell.